# Discarding everything above a slanted line in an image

Tags: image, matlab, processing

I am trying to discard (i.e. zero out) all of the pixels above a certain region in an image (for example, a clearly defined white bar). Is there any way I can use the result of a Sobel edge detection to accomplish this, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
I = imread('image.png');    % read image
E = edge(I)                 % get results of canny edge detector
[~,idx] = max( sum(E,2:) ); % find the row with the clearest horizontal edge
I(1:idx-1,:) = 0;           % zero everything above (not including) that row
```

You could probably replace the canny edge image with a Sobel image and get the same results.

Comment: Thanks @eigenchris. Do you have any ideas on how I might be able to adapt this to a slanted line?

Comment: @erythraios You could look into detecting the line using the [`hough`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/hough.html) and [`houghpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/houghpeaks.html) functions. You would need to zero the image column-by-column since the line height varies throughout the image.